# Error: unexpected token < in contact form

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Hi i am developing one site there is one contact form when i click on submit in console it is give error like "Unexpected Token <"

Here is the link for contact form .

```
http://192.185.83.133/~lbrisas/TRY/ibrisas/contact.html
```

Thanks
Vishal

Comment: Could you please add the code you are using to submit the form and the form markup to the question, only the relevant parts.

Comment: you are not getting `json` response from the server. Still you have to post your ajax code here to see what is happening or you have to find that on the serverside what you can do if your controller or server side is unable to produce json.

Comment: i have purchased theme and just integrate it . It is simple HTML page at the end of page where you can find two js for contact form one is "jquery.form.js" that is user for post data to php file